# How to limit TeamViewer 12 for one or more applications in Windows10?

Tags: teamviewer

I have looked at some old TeamViewer guides dealing with such limit and they distinct full mode from "Presentation mode" but I didn't encounter such distinction in TeamViewer 12.

Basically I mean to limit TeamViewer 12 for one or more applications in Win10? Say, for Chrome and/or Firefox in Windows10?

Comment: With TeamViewer you access the desktop and can do anything that the logged-on account can do. I don't see any other means than restricting the logged-in account. What say these guides that you have found?

Comment: I found nothing on this. I just heard someone saying, in some Facebook group once, I think, that once can limit TV for a certain program, like a browser or MS word or whatever, thought I'm no sure this is correct. in a quick search, I found nothing.

Comment: @harrymc, I can't believe you're unaware of TeamViewer's meeting function!

Comment: If you are starting the connection from the machine that is to be viewed, you can use the Presentation function (there are already answers showing how to do this below).  But there isn't a way to have TeamViewer acting as a host that is blindly accepting remote connections AND is limited to only showing a single app.  So, if you're running a meeting/presentation then yes you can limit what is show; but if you're doing regular remote support style connections you cannot.

Comment: @varfirstName: I think that Ruscal above answered this for me. There is no way to "limit TeamViewer 12 for one or more applications", all you can do is show one or more windows, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @harrymc You're right. What you can do is set up a VM to keep those applications in a container, isolated. At that point, though, it becomes a little bit too convoluted and unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to share one window with TeamViewer 12

If you go to **Meeting** (On the left side of the TeamViewer window, there are tabs. Meeting is one of them), then click on **Presentation** (This begins a meeting session), you should get the TeamViewer panel.

[image: tvpanel]

Then, if you hover over the Screen sharing preview (The section of the panel that shows what is being broadcasted to the viewers. By default, this shows your first screen), you should see an extra part at the bottom appear. The combo box (Drop down menu) is what we're after, as this allows us to modify what is shown.

[image: tvhoverl]

The combo box (which for example could say "Presenting screen 1") contains monitors, then a list of windows which are currently open.

[image: tvlist]

If you select a window, it will only share that window, and to your viewers the rest of the screen will be grayed out (By this, I mean that they can't see the rest of the screen, it is just gray). The preview window will show what the viewers will see.

### Multiple windows

Multiple windows is the same as above, except you select more windows to share.

Comment: I'm happy that you edited your post to include photos for Benia. You deserve the bounty, and need it much more than I do. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Lewis. Thanks. Can you please add parenthesis-level clarifications for "going for a meeting" and "presentation". Especially, why is this terminology needed? A clarification in parenthesis could make this more accessible to people new to TeamViewer...

Comment: @Benia all done.

Comment: Thanks. I also thumbed up. A small question please. Till now when I interacted with people with TV, I used "remote control" instead of "meeting". My question is this: Is it accurate to assume that the main difference between "remote control" and "meeting" is the option to limit TV just to a certain window? A note regarding this could be very helpful.

Comment: The meeting option is mainly used for presentations. Remote control is a way of letting a system administrator control your computer. As far as I know, the meeting option does not let you control the computer, only let you view it (unless specified permissions are granted). Remote control, on the other hand, let's you control it right off the bat. So it's safe to assume that meetings are used for presentations (mainly) and remote control is used for assistance with your computer, whether it be a system administrator in a company or if you are getting a friend to help on your home PC.

Answer (score 1):

Click **Meeting**, Then **Presentation**:

[image]

Then you'll see a Teamviewer screen. You need to click on **"Presenting screen 1"**:

[image]

It'll pop up a modal like this, but with different programs:

[image]

Then select the program you'd like to broadcast, and you're done!