# Teamviewer hide second monitor

Tags: teamviewer

I've been searching everywhere how you can hide/remove/cut access/any other term that would imply disabling multiple monitors on team viewer but all I can find is posts about it supporting multiple monitors. I don't want to share my second screen and I've been wondering how do you do this.

Answer (score 0):

In a **meeting** you can select to only share "screen 1" - or even just some applications, see the screenshots in [How to limit TeamViewer 12 for one or more applications in Windows10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1212694/how-to-limit-teamviewer-12-for-one-or-more-applications-in-windows10/1222812)